# How to remove notes refs in Gerrit

Tags: gerrit

We are using Gerrit 2.x. I have pushed a notes ref to Gerrit, e.g. `refs/notes/foobar`. Now I would like to remove that ref from the project in Gerrit. I am project owner but not Gerrit admin. How can this be accomplished?

- The UI lacks generic refs access, and no notes either
- The REST API only supports `branches` and `tags` endpoints (no `notes` nor `refs)
- Using the `branches` and `tags` REST API endbpoints, e.g. `.../branches/refs%2Fnotes%2F/foobar`
- I am unable to find anything related to this in documentation

Comment: have you tried to push empty ref? `git push origin :refs/original/refs/notes/foobar`

Comment: No, that was new to me. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Removing refs for notes can be done by removing the reference and pushing the removed reference to Gerrit:

```
git fetch -f origin refs/notes/foobar:refs/notes/foobar
git notes --ref foobar remove HEAD
git push ssh://gerrit.local:29418/my-project/baz.git refs/notes/foobar
```